# C++ FOR LOOP ONLY task

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

Ok, so i have this C++ task where, by using ONLY for loops, i have to create this table

1  5  9  13

2  6  10 14

3  7  11 15

4  8  12 16

And so far , with this line of code:

```
int n;
int count = 1;

cout << "Please enter N: "; cin >> n;
for (int i = 1;i<=n;i++)
{
    cout << i << ", ";
    for (int j = count;j<n;j++)
    {
        count+=n;
        cout << count << ", ";

    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

I manage to get only

```
1  5  9  13
2
3
4
```

What should i do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. You should note that the difference between any two consecutive entries in the row is n, and the first entry is the row number.

```
for (int i = 1;i<=n;i++)
{
    // loops from 0 to n-1
    for (int j = 0;j<n;j++)
    {

        cout << i + j*n << " ";

    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

If you want to reverse the even rows, then for those rows you will run the for loop backwards.

```
for (int i = 1;i<=n;i++)
{
    if ( i % 2 == 1 ) {

      for (int j = 0;j<n;j++)
        cout << i + j*n << " ";

    } else {

      for (int j = n-1; j>=0 ; j-- )
        cout << i + j*n << " ";

    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

If you want to reverse the even columns, then you can see the pattern.

```
for (int i = 1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= 4 ; j-- )
    {
        if ( j % 2 == 0 ) {

          cout << (5-i) + (j-1)*n << " ";

        }
        else
          cout << i + (j-1)*n << " ";

    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: And what modifications should i use if i want to invert the even columns? I have an idea of adding some if-case to check if the rows counter's current value is (% == 0), but don't know how to implement it without breaking the current working program..

Comment: No, i meant columns, not rows, it seems my programming skills have worsened my english as well

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot, plus, i actually understood it all! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `count` needs to be reset after or before the inner `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 1;i<=n;i++)
{
    cout << i << ", ";
// ***
    count = i;
// ***
    for (int j = count;j<n;j++)
    {
        count+=n;
        cout << count << ", ";

    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

You could simplify this as with Abishek's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
This problem can be solved by doing this coding.
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int i,j,n;
    for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        n=i;
        for (j=1;j<=4;j++)
        {
            cout<<n<<"\t";
            n=n+4;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    getch ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should give some explanation!

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= 13 ; i +=4) 
    {
        cout << i << " " ; 
    }
    cout << endl; 

    for (int x = 2 ; x <= 14 ; x+=4)
    {
        cout << x << " " ;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int y = 3 ; y <= 15 ; y+=4) 
    {
        cout << y << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int z = 4 ; z <= 16 ; z+=4) 
    {
        cout << z << " " ; 
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

This is my answer. I wrote it in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express and it gave me the write answer.